# Use IScroll in Angular 2 / Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, ionic2

i want to use a Javascript Libary called iscroll.

So far i got the iscroll.d.ts and now i want to use it, but iam new at typescript and dont know how to do that.

My iscroll.d.ts looks like this:

```
// Generated by typings
// Source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/types/typed-iscroll/8524f7c88e521c16462553173c9ea99e9e3d477c/iscroll.d.ts
declare module 'iscroll' {
class IScroll {
  version: string;

  constructor(element: string | HTMLElement, options?: IScroll.IScrollOptions);

  destroy(): void;
  resetPosition(time: number): boolean;
  disable(): void;
  enable(): void;
  refresh(): void;
  scrollTo(x: number, y: number, time?: number, easing?: IScroll.IScrollEaseOption): void;
  scrollBy(x: number, y: number, time?: number, easing?: IScroll.IScrollEaseOption): void;
  scrollToElement(el: HTMLElement | string, time?: number, offsetX?: number, offsetY?: number, easing?: IScroll.IScrollEaseOption): void;
  goToPage(x: number, y: number, time?: number, easing?: IScroll.IScrollEaseOption): void;
  prev(): void;
  next(): void;
  zoom(scale: number, x: number, y: number, time?: number): void;
  refresh(): void;
  destroy(): void;

  utils: IScroll.IScrollUtils;

  // Events
  on(type: 'beforeScrollStart' |
    'scrollCancel' |
    'scrollStart' |
    'scrollEnd' |
    'flick' |
    'zoomStart' |
    'zoomEnd', fn: (evt?: any) => void): void;
  off(type: string, fn?: (evt?: any) => void): void;

}

namespace IScroll {
  export interface IScrollIndicatorOptions {
    el?: HTMLElement | string;
    fade?: boolean;
    ignoreBoundaries?: boolean;
    interactive?: boolean;
    listenX?: boolean;
    listenY?: boolean;
    resize?: boolean;
    shrink?: boolean;
    speedRatioX?: number;
    speedRatioY?: number;
  }

  export interface IScrollKeyBindings {
    pageUp?: number | string,
    pageDown: number | string;
    end: number | string;
    home: number | string;
    left: number | string;
    up: number | string;
    right: number | string;
    down: number | string;
  }

  export interface IScrollOptions {

    indicators?: IScrollIndicatorOptions;

    // Scrollbar
    scrollbars?: boolean | string;
    fadeScrollbars?: boolean;
    interactiveScrollbars?: boolean;
    resizeScrollbars?: boolean;
    shrinkScrollbars?: boolean;

    // Zoom
    zoom?: boolean;
    zoomMin?: number;
    zoomMax?: number;
    startZoom?: number;
    wheelAction?: string;

    snap?: boolean | string;

    bindToWrapper?: boolean;
    bounceEasing?: string | IScrollEaseOption;
    bounceTime?: number;
    deceleration?: number;
    mouseWheelSpeed?: number;
    preventDefaultException?: any;
    resizePolling?: number;
    probeType?: number;
    keyBindings?: boolean | IScrollKeyBindings;

    useTransform?: boolean;
    useTransition?: boolean;
    HWCompositing?: boolean;
    bounce?: boolean;
    click?: boolean;
    disableMouse?: boolean;
    disablePointer?: boolean;
    disableTouch?: boolean;
    eventPassthrough?: boolean;
    freeScroll?: boolean;
    invertWheelDirection?: boolean;
    momentum?: boolean;
    mouseWheel?: boolean;
    preventDefault?: boolean;
    tap?: boolean | string;

    scrollX?: number;
    scrollY?: number;
    startX?: number;
    startY?: number;

    // Infinite options
    infiniteElements: HTMLElement | 'string';
    cacheSize: number;
    dataset: (start: number, count: number) => Object[];
  }

  export interface IScrollEaseOption {
    style: 'string';
    fn: Function;
  }
  export interface IScrollEaseOptions {
    quadratic: IScrollEaseOption;
    circular: IScrollEaseOption;
    back: IScrollEaseOption;
    bounce: IScrollEaseOption;
    elastic: IScrollEaseOption;
  }

  export interface IScrollUtils {
    ease: IScrollEaseOptions;
  }
}

export = IScroll;
}
```

And my Angular 2 page.ts looks like this:

```
import {NavController} from "ionic-angular";
import {AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from "angularfire2";
import {OnInit, Inject, Component} from "@angular/core";
import {UserService} from '../../../services/UserService';
import {AuthPage} from "../home/home";
import { IScroll } from "iscroll"

@Component({
    templateUrl: "build/pages/auth/onboarding/onboarding.html",
    providers: [UserService]
})

export class OnboardingPage {

    iScroll: IScroll;

    onboardingStep: number = 1;
```

The Import works fine so far, i think but i dont know how to init and use iscroll.

Hope some of you got any tips how to bring that to life :)

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use this library as well, but can get no where near as far as you.. I can't event import ..[my issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51307505/how-to-use-iscroll-in-an-angular-typescript-project). How did you import, what npm packages did you use (*perhaps you have a different version that worked>

Answer (score 4):

You use it just like you'd use it in plain old javascript, with the difference that you can also include types.

For example, javascript:

```
let myScroll = new IScroll("#CONTAINER_ID");
```

typescript:

```
let myScroll: IScroll = new IScroll("#CONTAINER_ID");
```

(notice that the `: IScroll` isn't needed, the compiler can infer the type, but I added it to make a point)

In your case:

```
export class OnboardingPage {
    iScroll: IScroll;

    constructor() {
        this.iScroll = new IScroll("#CONTAINER_ID");
    }
}
```

This code is based on their documentation (https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll) but according to the `.d.ts` file you posted it requires to use the `iscroll` namespace:

```
let myScroll = new iscroll.IScroll("#CONTAINER_ID");
```

Hope this helps.