# How to use IScroll in an Angular / TypeScript project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an Angular (Ionic) application where I need momentum scrolling for desktop (running inside Electron).

One promising way of doing this may be to use [IScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5), however I cannot get this to load.

I have installed so I have the following in my `package.json`

```
 "iscroll": "^5.2.0",
```

and also installed the typings via  `npm install @types/iscroll@5.2.1`

First, I could not import, I get an error:

> [ts] File 'd:/dev/capacitor/electron2/node_modules/@types/iscroll/index.d.ts' is not a module.

I then tried adding the following to the bottom of `iscroll/index.d.ts`:

```
export {IScroll};
```

It now seemed to remove the error.

I now added the following code:

```
 public ngAfterViewInit() {
   var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
   var myScroll = new IScroll(wrapper);
 }
```

(I know I should, and will, use `@ViewChild()` just trying to get it working initially)

This builds OK, but when I go to the test page, I get the following error:

```
        Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_iscroll__.IScroll is not a constructor
    TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_iscroll__.IScroll is not a constructor
        at ListPage.webpackJsonp.190.ListPage.ngAfterViewInit (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:114:24)
        at callProviderLifecycles (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13122:18)
```

In the type definition, we do have the following:

```
declare class IScroll {
  constructor (element: string, options?: IScrollOptions);
  constructor (element: HTMLElement, options?: IScrollOptions);
```

How can I get this working?

### Update 1

My next attempt was to remove the export from the type definition, try and import as follows.

```
import  'iscroll';
```

The app builds and run with no TypeScript error, until we enter the page that instantiates the IScroll, where  error now becomes

```
    Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: IScroll is not defined
    ReferenceError: IScroll is not defined
        at ListPage.webpackJsonp.190.ListPage.ngAfterViewInit (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:116:24)
        at callProviderLifecycles (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13122:18)
```

So, still no where.

### Update 2

Tried the suggestions from @Jamshed

```
 import * as IScroll from 'iscroll'; or
 import IScroll from 'iscroll'; or
 import { IScroll } from 'iscroll'
```

All of these give

```
[ts] File 'd:/dev/capacitor/electron2/node_modules/@types/iscroll/index.d.ts' is not a module
```

I did try just adding the "old way".

So in index.html I added

```
<script src='D:/dev/capacitor/electron2/node_modules/iscroll/build/iscroll-lite.js'></script>
```

and then the `declare var IScroll: any;` in the ts component file.

But once again I get

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: IScroll is not defined
    ReferenceError: IScroll is not defined
```

at runtime.

### Update 3

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551237/use-iscroll-in-angular-2-typescript), but if I copy his `index.d.ts` file into mine, I still cannot `import {IScroll}`. I can see a number of other exports, in there, but not IScroll.

[image]

Comment: try import * as IScroll from 'iscroll'; or try import IScroll from 'iscroll'; or try import { IScroll } from 'iscroll';

Comment: or import in to your index.html and then declare var IScroll; in you some.component.ts

Comment: Thanks @Jamshed, I've added comments to these as UPDATE2 so can get the formatting.

Comment: I have a follow up to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54006395/how-to-get-iscroll-to-work-in-an-ionic-angular-application) where I use a "manual workaround" to get the library at least loading..

Answer (score 0):

I know, already 3 years passed. But i ran into similar need today and found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/iscroll

Just add it to dependencies it will create a Typescript filler